# How to encrypt my web traffic?

Tags: networking, security, wifi, encryption

I am using a wireless LAN (or sometimes a wired connection) connection for web surfing and any one from my campus can use the network.

I simply want to encrypt my all data which is going between my computer and my campus server.

Please tell me how I can do this?  I am asking about tutorials or details.

Is there any tool or software for this?

- Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're not going to mention what operating system your server and computer are running it's hard to point you at tutorials.

Comment: @Cry Havok,i am using UBUNTU 10.04 and apache2.2

Comment: @Cry Havok,My campus server is using windows server 2003 as OS and apache2 as server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what your "campus" server is.

With encryption, you need an end point to decrypt the data. So your computer/laptop encrypts the data, and a computer on the other end decrypts it.

If you don't have access to a computer on the other end to do the decryption, then a service like http://www.hotspotvpn.com/ would be the easy solution. Also, https://secure.logmein.com has something last I looked.

Tor http://www.torproject.org would even do the job, but it tends to be slow.

If you have a computer on the other end you can use, be it a hosted solution, or a home computer, then http://openvpn.net would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

First you must have direct administrative access to the server, if that is the case, then the options are:

- Configure the hosted application for SSL (e.g. HTTPS for web) access
- Configure a VPN on the server(s) and access the server(s) through the VPN(s)

Answer (score 0):

encryption depends on the protocol you are using.
What is your 'campus server' exactly ?

for example, protocols based on TCP, like HTTP, IMAP or FTP often have a secured version that uses the cryptographic TLS protocol. They are called the same with a S at the end : HTPS, IMAPS, FTPS.

For SSH connection, it's already secured. SSH is the secured version of the good old telnet (with improvements also).

If you connect using wireless, the connection is probably already secured with WPA. But that's just between your computer and the wireless access point. For end-to-end security, you need to look at what is provided by the server you connect to.

Answer (score 0):

Rent a desktop from amazon ec2 and browse from there.
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

Answer (score 0):

Tor does not encrypt your communication. You can set up socks with your server (if you have any) with firefox. http://articles.slicehost.com/2009/1/6/ssh-socks-proxy

This will encrypt your web traffic until your ssh server.